# Updating d3 chart added when geojson polygon is clicked to leaflet map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I created a d3 chart div on a leaflet.js map by:

```
<div id="map">
    <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left">
        <div id="chart"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The `leaflet-bottom leaflet-left` embeds the div in the bottom left corner on the map. I also added geojson and would like to know how to update the d3 in the div when a different geojson poylgon is clicked. Currently, when I click one polygon it the bar chart appears then. However when I click another it does not update. The javascript to do this for the click in the onEachFeature function is:

```
click: function(e){
           var barnum = [];
           var barcat = []
           /* pm25 holds data to create d3 bar chart */
           for(var i = 0; i < pm25.length; i++){                                                         
               if(feature.properties.BoroCD == pm25[i][1]){                                                                   
                   if(data[i].Year.startsWith('Annual')){                                                                        
                       barnum.push(data[i].Mean);                                                                         
                       barcat.push(data[i].Year);
                   }
               }
           }
           var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                     .domain([0, d3.max(barnum)])
                     .range([0, 100])

           d3.select("#chart")
             .selectAll("div")
             .data(barnum)
             .enter().append("div")
             .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
             .text(function(d) { return d; });
     }
```

How would I go about updating the chart when clicking different polygons? I have the full code [here](https://github.com/janicedarling/CSC59969Project/tree/master/Dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 d3.select("#chart")
         .selectAll("div")
         .data(barnum)
         .enter().append("div")
         .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
         .text(function(d) { return d; })
         .on("mouseover", function (d) {}
                    })
         .on("mouseout", function (d) {}
                        }
                    })
         .on("mousedown", d => {})
         .on("click", scope.select);
```

Hope it helps. Along with click you can also use other properties like "mouseover", "mouseout" and "mousedown"